Issue obtaining file path in Electron + React
I've been trying to get the path of a dragged file from a React component in Electron for a few days now, but without success.
I've looked at other forum topics, and everyone is able to obtain it using e.dataTransfer.files[0].path, but in my case that is undefined. I've also tried using preload.js to get whether it's a file or path, following a YouTube tutorial, doing the following:
React Component:
function LeftMenu() {
  const handleDrop = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const file = e.dataTransfer.files[0];
    if (file) {
      const isFile = await window.api.isFile();
      console.log(isFile);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div
      className='left-menu'
      style={{ width: `${leftMenuWidth}px` }}
      onDragOver={(e) => [e.preventDefault(), e.stopPropagation()]}
      onDrop={handleDrop}
    >
      <div></div>
      <div className='resizer' onMouseDown={handleMouseDown} />
    </div>
  )
}

Preload.js:
const { contextBridge, ipcRenderer } = require('electron');

const api = {
  isFile: (path) => ipcRenderer.invoke('is-file', path),
};

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('api', api);

Main.js:
ipcMain.handle('is-file', async (_, path) => {
  return fs.lstatSync(path).isFile();
})

But without success, path is still undefined, receiving this error:

TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer or URL. Received undefined

Additionally, in the preload path, I've had to redirect the route to renderer/main_window from main.js. Is this normal in Webpack? Or am I doing something wrong?
const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
  width: 800,
  height: 600,
  webPreferences: {
    preload: path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'renderer', 'main_window', 'preload.js'),
    nodeIntegration: false,
    contextIsolation: true,
    enableRemoteModule: false,
  },
  autoHideMenuBar: true,
});

I've searched through multiple forums and topics, but haven't found anything related to my specific error. I've only found information about using Electron without Webpack, where using .path works.

I will vote to close this question as caused by a typo. Look at your const isFile = await window.api.isFile(); call, isn't there something missing? (:

Yes, pass the file or path in the function. But it still doesn't work. I've also tried using event.dataTransfer.files[0].path and it's undefined, I can get the folder name but not the path.
